# QElapsedTimer hasExpired() - Is it one msec off?

Tags: c++, qt

Here is a a part of the documentation of Qt's **QElapsedTimer**:

```
bool QElapsedTimer::hasExpired(qint64 timeout) const
```

> Returns true if this QElapsedTimer has already expired by timeout milliseconds (that is, **more than timeout milliseconds have elapsed**). The value of timeout can be -1 to indicate that this timer does not expire, in which case this function will always return false.

Shouldn't it rather be implemented as **more than timeout -1 milliseconds have elapsed** ?

EDIT:
My idea about **More than timeout -1** is definitely incorrect. What I really wanted to ask was wether the explanation of **more than** may be incorrect and I think it precisely should be **equal or more than**.

Comment: Questions that ask *why* some software was designed the way it is are a bit difficult: we aren't the designers, we don't really know. But this documented behaviour seems perfectly fine to me, and is shared by many other timer implementations. Could you explain why you think that one millisecond should be ignored, i.e. why `hasExpired(1)` should always and immediately be true? Why one millisecond, and not one second or microsecond?

Comment: It shouldn't. My intention for asking was more like: Think about waiting for, e.g., 100 ms and an internal timer precision of 1 ms. I'd expect hasExpired() to return true after 100 ms and not after 101. In that  particular moment when the timer value reaches 100 then it already has expired.

Answer (score 1):

No. Because then a 1ms timer would elapse after 0.0000001ms

I guess "x or more milliseconds" might be better wording/implementation but whats the precision of the underlying measurement?

Also consider time spans. Say I have a start time of 0 and an end time of 100. Is 100 within the time span or do I say that the span is over when t > 100

If I say 100 is within the span, then 0 must be outside it. Otherwise I cant put spans back to back.

Comment: Yes,  X or more is what I think would be correct. When I implement timers manually I always compare the current value <= against the timeout value.